# How can I edit the rows of data in a table using data from a database?

Tags: php, html, css

How can I format and style the rows of data in this table where it's displaying my data?

```
    <table class="table">
    <tr bgcolor=" #b366ff">
                 <th>Game</th>                     
                 <th>Date</th>
                 <th>Score</th>
                 <th>Venue</th>
        </tr>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM game WHERE username = '{$users}' AND savename = '{$saves}';";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
?>
<?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
           echo "<td>".$row['team']."</td>";
           echo "<td>".$row['date']."</td>";
           echo "<td>".$row['score']."</td>";
           echo "<td>".$row['venue']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: The same way you would have done it if the data had been hard coded

Comment: depending upon how and where you derive the variables `$users` & `$saves` you may (probably) be open to sql injection because of the use of these variables directly in the sql.

Comment: Your title says "edit", but your question says "format and style". Which is it?

Comment: The question title and the actual question are completely different...

Answer (score 2):

using a CSS class?

```
<style>
.tr1{background-color:#333;}
.td1{background-color:#999;}
</style>

echo "<tr class="tr1">";
echo "<td class="td1">".$row['team']."</td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do same as you do in normal HTML, you can use

```
.table tr{
background-color: grey;
}
```

Also you can use nth child selecter to style the elements.